# How to turn off setting for visible special characters In outlook new email message?

Tags: special-characters, outlook-2007

Somehow I turned on the display paragraph marks, spaces, and other special characters in my outlook 2007 new email messages and I can't find a way to turn it off.

I am looking for the outlook equivalent of the Word 2007 Show/Hide command that is in the paragraph section of the toolbar ribbon, whose icon in the toolbar is a paragraph mark.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer :

1. Create a new message.
2. Right click on the tabs line of the menu and
3. select -> Customize Quick Access Toolbar
4. select -> Display
5. Uncheck box -> Show all formatting marks.

Answer (score 27):

None of the other answers worked on my outlook 2010. However, ctrl+shift+8 did the trick.

Comment: The shortcut works in Outlook 2013 as well!

Comment: How we can do it in web mail ?

Comment: Just wanted to add, for Office 2016, you can't toggle this feature using ctrl+shift+8 from the inline editor, you have to click the "New Email" button and use the keyboard shortcut in the new editor window.

Answer (score 5):

In Outlook 2010, when viewing a message, choose

1. File
2. Options
3. Compose Message
4. Editor Options button.

Then under Display, tick/untick the box to 'Show all formatting marks'.

However, Microsoft doesn't provide this easily because it's under the group 'format text'/'paragraph' when customizing the ribbon, which is greyed out when viewing the message.

To add it yourself, create a custom group (I called mine 'View Format' in the ribbon (eg under the Message tab), then show all commands on the left. Choose 'Show All' and add it to your custom group.

Answer (score 0):

Press CTRL+SHIFT+8 to toggle the “Show markup” feature on/off.